# Create plane with UV Based offset

Tags: 3d, blender, unreal-engine5

I am a newbie to 3D and only know a little bit about Blender.
I was following a tutorial for a seamless portal system for Unreal Engine and suddenly it asked me to model a very complicated 3d shape.

Can someone help me create this in Blender?
(tutorial link: https://www.froyok.fr/blog/2019-03-creating-seamless-portals-in-unreal-engine-4/#final_result)

"Plane 1 : The main plane which will display the Portal render target. This plane is a bit special because its goal is to be pushed away when the player gets close. This is in order to avoid the clipping of the camera. Because the Plane borders don’t move but only its middle vertices it allows the player to overlap the Portal rendering without visual artifacts. The faces at the border have their UVs at the bottom half while the inner faces have their UVs at the top half which makes them easy separate via a mask in a shader (see gif below).
Plane 2 : This one is only here as a way to expand the default Bounding Box of the mesh. The vertex normals are pointing downward so that even on non-flat ground the mesh won’t be visible by default (because the rendering material will not be two-sided)."
[image]
[image]

"I designed Plane 1 to be stretched when the player gets close to it. This allows to overlap and walk on the portal without clipping (cutting) it. This can happen if for example the camera did not cross the portal plane yet but the player’s legs did. It avoids managing to clip the player and duplicating its mesh on the other side.

For Plane 2 The goal is to expand the default bounding box of the mesh. Because Plane 1 being a plane, the bounding box on one axis is 0 and if the camera end-up behind, it would be culled by the engine (aka not rendering it anymore). Plane 1 has a size of 128×128 so that it can be easily scaled in-engine. Plane 2 is slightly bigger and below the floor (below 0)."